# $\mathcal C^0[0,1]$ is not complete with the norm $\|f\|=\int_0^1|f|$.

Tags: real-analysis

I know that $V:=\mathcal C^0[0,1]$ is not complete with the norm $\|f\|=\int_0^1|f|$. But in my official solution, they said that it's not complete because $f_n(x):=x^n$ is Cauchy sequence but it doesn't converges in $V$ because it converges to $x\mapsto \boldsymbol 1_{\{1\}}(x)$.

**My Questions**

Doesn't it converges to $0$ in $V$ ? indeed $$\|f_n\|=\int_0^1 x^n\,\mathrm d x=\frac{1}{n+1}\underset{n\to \infty }{\longrightarrow }0.$$

Am I mistaken somewhere ?

Comment: $f_n$ does converge to $0$ (but your calculation is wrong, $\|f_n\|=\dfrac{1}{n+1}$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the official solution makes a common mistake even good mathematicians make at times.

Let $f_n$ be the piecewise linear function in $C=C[0,1]$ that connects the points $(0,0), (1/2,0), (1/2+1/n,1),(1,1).$ Good to draw a picture here.

Exercise: Show $(f_n)$ is Cauchy in $(C,\|\,\|).$

Now suppose $f\in C$ and $\|f_n-f\|\to 0.$ Claim: $f=0$ on $(0,1/2).$ Proof: Suppose $f(a)>0$ for some $a\in (0,1/2).$ Then there is a $\delta>0$ such that $I=(a-\delta,a+\delta)\subset (0,1/2),$ and such that $f>f(a)/2$ in $I.$ If follows that for every $n,$

$$\int_0^1|f-f_n| \ge \int_I|f-f_n| \ge (f(a)/2)\cdot (2\delta).$$

That is a contradiction, hence $f\le 0$ on $(0,1/2).$ Similarly $f\ge 0$ on $(0,1/2).$ The claim is proved.

In much the same way we can show $f=1$ on $(1/2,1).$ (I'll leave this to you.) Because $f$ is continuous, we see $f(1/2)=0$ and $f(1/2)=1,$ contradiction. Thus $(f_n)$ is Cauchy in $(C,\|\,\|)$ yet converges to no $f\in C.$